# How to prevent XtraGrid TextEdit from losing focus when moving cursor beyond contents

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtragrid, textedit

I am using an `XtraGrid` from `DeveloperExpress` with a column holding strings, edited via a TextEdit control.

When a user enters edit mode (the editor is shown), the text is automatically selected, just as it is in for example Windows Explorer when you hit **F2** having something selected.

Now, if the user presses left/right, the focus moves away from the current cell into the cell immediately to the left/right (may also be the cell above/below depending on the column layout).

The same thing happens in the user deselects the contents of the editor by for example press home/end and then moves the caret all the way to the left/right in the cell (to the first/last char) and then moves it another step, "beyond" the contents.

In Windows Explorer, doing the same thing just keeps the caret at the left/rightmost position, it never leaves edit mode unless terminated via for example hitting **Escape**.
Even in Excel, edit mode is not terminated when hitting the left/right cell boundary whilst editing the contents of a cell.

I would like the same behavior in my XtraGrid when in edit mode, but I cannot find any setting or way to do it.

Has anyone run into this problem and found a way to overcome it?
Am I perhaps thinking backwards here?
I really want to have my application to behave in a consistent and "standard Windows" way as much as possible, which I do not feel is the case as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
    private void gridControl1_EditorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = (sender as GridControl).FocusedView as GridView;
        VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit edit = view.ActiveEditor as VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit;
        if (edit == null) return;
        if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "FirstName" && view.FocusedRowHandle % 2 == 0)
        {
            e.Handled = (e.KeyData == Keys.Right && edit.SelectionStart == edit.Text.Length) ||
                (e.KeyData == Keys.Left && edit.SelectionStart == 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this. Although a bit more code is needed to handle all cases, created a new answer with my solution since I cannot edit answers.

Answer (score 2):

My full solution:

```
private void UiGridControlEditorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData != Keys.Left && e.KeyData != Keys.Right)
        return;

    var gridControl = sender as GridControl;
    if (gridControl == null) return;

    var view = gridControl.FocusedView as GridView;
    if (view == null) return;

    var textEdit = view.ActiveEditor as TextEdit;
    if (textEdit == null) return;

    var left = e.KeyData == Keys.Left;
    var right = e.KeyData == Keys.Right;

    // Handle initial case - everything selected in control
    if ((left || right) && 
        textEdit.SelectionLength == textEdit.Text.Length && 
        textEdit.SelectionStart == 0)
    {
        var leftPosition = textEdit.Text.Length - 1 < 0 ? 
                           0 : textEdit.Text.Length - 1;
        var rightPosition = textEdit.Text.Length;

        textEdit.SelectionStart = left ? leftPosition : rightPosition;
        textEdit.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;

        return;
    }

    // Handle left & rightmost positions (prevent focus change)
    e.Handled = left && textEdit.SelectionStart == 0 ||
                right && textEdit.SelectionStart == textEdit.Text.Length;
}
```